# IOS : NSString retrieving a substring from a string

Tags: iphone, ios, string, nsstring

Hey I am looking for a way to extract a string from another string.  It could be any length and be in any part of the string so the usual methods don't work.

For example
http://bla.com/bla?id=%1234%&something=%888%

What I want to extract is from id=% to the next %.

Any idea's?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484826/retrieving-particular-lines-of-text-from-string-memory-management-issues][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484826/retrieving-particular-lines-of-text-from-string-memory-management-issues

this was my question.. follow it

Comment: check this link. its simple and useful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5806879/1635315

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use the rangeOfString method:

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"id=%"];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
   //range.location is start of substring
   //range.length is length of substring
}
```

You can then chop up the string using the `substringWithRange:`, `substringFromIndex:` and `substringToIndex:` methods to get the bits you want. Here's a solution to your specific problem:

```
NSString *param = nil;
NSRange start = [string rangeOfString:@"id=%"];
if (start.location != NSNotFound)
{
    param = [string substringFromIndex:start.location + start.length];
    NSRange end = [param rangeOfString:@"%"];
    if (end.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        param = [param substringToIndex:end.location];
    }
}

//param now contains your value (or nil if not found)
```

Alternatively, here's a general solution for extracting query parameters from a URL, which may be more useful if you need to do this several times:

```
- (NSDictionary *)URLQueryParameters:(NSURL *)URL
{
    NSString *queryString = [URL query];
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSArray *parameters = [queryString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    for (NSString *parameter in parameters)
    {
        NSArray *parts = [parameter componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        if ([parts count] > 1)
        {
            NSString *key = [parts[0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSString *value = [parts[1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            result[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This doesn't strip the % characters from the values, but you can do that either with

```
NSString *value = [[value substringToIndex:[value length] - 1] substringFromIndex:1];
```

Or with something like

```
NSString *value = [value stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"%" withString:@""];
```

---

**UPDATE:** As of iOS 8+ theres a built-in class called `NSURLComponents` that can automatically parse query parameters for you (`NSURLComponents` is available on iOS 7+, but the query parameter parsing feature isn't).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

> NSArray* foo = [@"10/04/2011" componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"];
>
> NSString* day = [foo objectAtIndex: 0];